# Why is this cyclic reference with a type projection illegal?

Tags: scala, types

The following pseudo-Scala yields an "illegal cyclic reference" error:

```
trait GenT[A]
trait T extends GenT[T#A] {
  type A
}
```

**Questions**: Why is this illegal? Is there a fundamental problem with soundness, or is it a limitation of the Scala type system? Is there a work-around?

My intent is to create a trait `T` with a type member `A` that can be lifted on demand to a type parameter via the super-trait `GenT[A]`. One application might be the expression of constraints, for example

```
def foo[A, S1 <: GenT[A], S2 <: GenT[A]] ...
```

This could be used as if it were `def foo[S1 <: T, S2 <:T] ...` with the constraint that `S1#A == S2#A`.

If the technique were possible, it might also help for the question: [How to specialize on a type projection in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631155/how-to-specialize-on-a-type-projection-in-scala)

Note: I could use `GenT` instead of `T` everywhere, but I'm trying to avoid that because it would cause lots of type parameters to spread across all my code "infectiously".

The two questions below seem similar but are about a different type of cyclic reference:

- [Scala: working around the "illegal cyclic reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732454/scala-working-around-the-illegal-cyclic-reference)
- [How to define a cyclic type definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253510/how-to-define-a-cyclic-type-definition)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your initial example you can break the cycle by introducing an auxiliary type inbetween GenT[A] and T,

```
trait GenT[A]
trait TAux { type A }
trait T extends TAux with GenT[TAux#A]
```

But from your motivating example I don't think you need to go down this route. The constraint you're after can be expressed directly using a refinement,

```
trait T { type A }
def foo[A0, S1 <: T { type A = A0 }, S2 <: T { type A = A0 }] ...
```

Also bear in mind that you can surface a type member as a type parameter via a type alias,

```
trait T { type A }
type TParam[A0] = T { type A = A0 }
def foo[A0, S1 <: TParam[A0], S2 <: TParam[A0]] ...
```

Comment: Great info, thanks! I was indeed trying to surface the type member.